# Can a jar file containing aspects and classes self instrument safely

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, aspects

if I have an instrumented jar file that contains compiled aspects and compiled classes can I instrument that jar with itself?

If I repeat this with the output jar does behavior get duplicated or is the second output identical to the first?

Comment: I have answered and commented your original question sufficiently, I guess. I suggest you (a) accept my answer below and (b) create a new question in which you explain what you actually want to achieve. I will be glad to answer that question, too, so you can finally solve your problem.

Comment: I know this one is old, but still listed as unanswered. Would you please accept and upvote my answer if it seems appropriate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just could have tried. Have you?

Anyway, the answer is no. The output will be identical. Think about it: You cannot reweave a class with the same aspect twice because the aspect is also just a class when translated into bytecode, and the same class cannot exist twice in the JVM, unless in isolated classloaders.

Why do you want to do this anyway? What is the use case?

Comment: This doesn't map to my understanding of over-weaving works. You could for instance write an around annotation woven over a func foo and end up with around(around(foo())).

Comment: Well, then your understanding just does not map to AspectJ joinpoint and pointcut semantics. Why don't you just create another advice for the same pointcut? That is easily possible. If you need a certain order of precedence, either use `declare precedence` for different aspects or, if your advice are in the same aspect, take care to read the [advice precedence](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html#advice-precedence) section of AspectJ documentation.

Comment: BTW, when you talk about "over-weaving" maybe you mean what is usually called re-weaving. This is also easily possible, just not the way you thought. Try to learn about AspectJ basics and semantics in order to understand how to solve your problem with a different approach (and probably better design). Wishful thinking will not help you here, I am afraid.

Comment: http://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fandrewclement.blogspot.com%2F2010%2F05%2Faspectj-overweaving.html&ei=O7BVUOj7M9CfiAfK74DgDg&usg=AFQjCNHZVapdX9W1_bIhmjGjvRe3gkaaEg&cad=rja

Comment: Even with overweaving I do not expect an aspect (still == JVM class) to exist twice, but I have not tried because over-weaving causes exceptions in my current build environment. What happens if you try? And again the question: What do you want to achieve? What is the use case? You still have not answered that. Maybe I can tell you how to do that.